# TicTacToe - checkWinner

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a code for a simple console aplication, but however it doesn't output wheter there is a winner or not. Here is my code. I tried to search for errors, but couldn't find it myself.
`

```
public class TicTacToe {

    static ArrayList<Integer> plaeyer1position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> plaeyer2position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] board = {{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
                {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
                {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}};

        gameboard(board);

        while(true) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Geben Sie die Position ein (1-9):");
            int position = scn.nextInt();
            bestimmmung_der_position(board, position, "Spieler 1");

            System.out.println("Geben Sie die Position ein (1-9):");
            int position2 = scn.nextInt();
            bestimmmung_der_position(board, position2, "Spieler 2");

            gameboard(board);

            String result = checkWinner();
            System.out.println(result);
        }


        }



    public static void gameboard(char[][] board) {
        for (char[] row : board) {
            for (char c : row) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void bestimmmung_der_position(char[][] board,int position, String spieler) {

        char symbol = ' ';

        if(spieler.equals("Spieler 1")){
            symbol = 'X';
            plaeyer1position.add(position);
        } else if (spieler.equals("Spieler 2")) {
            symbol = 'O';
            plaeyer2position.add(position);
        }


        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                board[0][0] = symbol;
                break;
            case 2:
                board[0][2] = symbol;
                break;
            case 3:
                board[0][4] = symbol;
                break;
            case 4:
                board[2][0] = symbol;
                break;
            case 5:
                board[2][2] = symbol;
                break;
            case 6:
                board[2][4] = symbol;
                break;
            case 7:
                board[4][0] = symbol;
                break;
            case 8:
                board[4][2] = symbol;
                break;
            case 9:
                board[4][4] = symbol;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        gameboard(board);
    }

    public static String checkWinner(){

        List top_zeile = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        List mid_zeile = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
        List bot_zeile = Arrays.asList(7,8,9);

        List links_reihe = Arrays.asList(1,4,7);
        List mitte_reihe = Arrays.asList(2,5,8);
        List rechts_reihe = Arrays.asList(3,6,9);

        List diagonale_rechts = Arrays.asList(1,5,9);
        List diagonale_links = Arrays.asList(7,5,3);

        List<List> gewinner = new ArrayList<List>();
        gewinner.add(top_zeile);
        gewinner.add(mid_zeile);
        gewinner.add(bot_zeile);
        gewinner.add(links_reihe);
        gewinner.add(mitte_reihe);
        gewinner.add(rechts_reihe);
        gewinner.add(diagonale_links);
        gewinner.add(diagonale_rechts);

        for(List l: gewinner){
            if(plaeyer1position.contains(l)){
                return "Spieler 1 gewonnen";
            } else if (plaeyer2position.contains(l)) {
                return "Spieler 2 gewonnen";
            }
            else if(plaeyer1position.size()+plaeyer2position.size()==9){
                return "Kein Spieler hat gewonnen.\n";
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

`

I expected my funktion "checkWinner" to check wheter there is a winning combination and output a winner if the combination has been matched.

Comment: `player1position` and `player2position` are `List`s of integers. `l` is an element of `gewinner`, which means it is a `List<Integer>`. How can a `List<Integer>` contain a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: The compiler should be warning you about this. Use `List<>` instead of `List` to have the compiler infer the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the `X.containsAll(Y)` function to check if `X` contains all elements in `Y`.
[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the following condition

```
plaeyer1position.contains(l)
```

This code will check if `ArrayList<Integer> plaeyer1position` contains `List<Integer> l`

However, `plaeyer1position` does not contain `List` objects; it contains `Integer` objects

So, **the condition will never be true**

Try using this instead (same for `plaeyer2position`)

```
plaeyer1position.containsAll(l)
```

`X.containsAll(Y)` will check if `X` contains all elements found in `Y`

Comment: i tryed it with `player1position.containsAll(l)` as well, but it din't really changed anything.

Comment: I found solution, thank you for the hint: I changed line 88 (List<List> to ArrayList<List>) and it worked